# How can I delete a Visual Studio project outside of Visual Studio without wreaking havoc on the solution?

Tags: xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2013, xamarin

After installing Xamarin for Visual Studio (2013) yesterday, opening VS 2013 today I get a never-ending dialog that says, "using Xamarin.iOS with Visual Studio requres Business edition or higher...updating licenses"

The VS message at the bottom of VS (blue strip) alternates between:

"*Reloading project file 'bla'*"

-and:

"*Unloading project file 'bla'*"

BTW, I added the project iOS project yesterday, but, although it was added to my solution, it says, "(unavailable)".

So, I reckon I can solve this by removing that project from the solution; but VS is in "suspended animation." What can I do to get rid of this project so VS will work again?

### UPDATE

Trying to solve this via demoncodemonkey's method, I opened the .sln file in Notepad++ and searched for "iOS" (the problematic project is named project "Bla_iOsUni").

Nothing was found...???

So I then searched for "project" and this is all there is:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HandheldServer", "HandheldServer\HandheldServer.csproj", "{DD275910-FC58-4CA8-884A-A0185EAFDE70}"
EndProject

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "WebAndLoadTestProject1", "WebAndLoadTestProject1\WebAndLoadTestProject1.csproj", "{714AB6D9-8108-4C5A-BBA2-68C16A92C26E}"
EndProject

Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{370DB360-2494-4365-A9E7-5844B24B4CED}"
    ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
        Local.testsettings = Local.testsettings
    EndProjectSection
EndProject

Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "UnitTestProject1", "UnitTestProject1\UnitTestProject1.csproj", "{CE84DF05-6314-4B76-A8DA-5CD2D99D7A5F}"
EndProject
```

So it shows the "main" project ("HandheldServer"); a test project ("WebAndLoadTestProject1"); some other apparently test-related thing ("Solution Items"); and yet another test project ("UnitTestProject1").

### UPDATE 2

Okay, this did it (following demoncodemonkey's suggestion):

I removed the problem project itself (the relevant "Project/EndProject" bit).

Also, I removed everything from the "GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution" section that had the string "iPhone" in it.

I thought I might have to remove some "iPhone" entries from the "GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution" section, too, but that was not necessary - I was able to open the project without doing that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always remove a project from a solution. Open the .sln in Notepad and remove the references to your project.

You'll need to remove the following lines:

```
Project("solutionGuid") = "projectName", "projectFilename", "projectGuid"
EndProject
```

as well as the associated lines in this solution configuration section:

```
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
  ...
  projectGuid.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
  projectGuid.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
  projectGuid.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
  projectGuid.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
  ...
```

and maybe the nested projects section:

```
GlobalSection(NestedProjects) = preSolution
  ...
  projectGuid = anotherProjectGuid
  ...
```

Comment: What about the "(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms)" section? (that also has some "iPhone" references).